# how to let vim list tags instead of jump to the first matched one when using vim -t sometag

Tags: vim, ctags

I'd like to make vim show a list of matched tags when using vim -t sometags instead of show the first matched one.

Thanks for advance.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can't change the way `-t` works. However, you can do something else:

```
vim +"ts sometag"
```

(See `:help :tselect`)

Comment: I know ts and use it always. I remember -t can works like ts or g[, just cannot make it work after work in current company. Maybe I get a memory crack?

Comment: @XinweiGong I don't think it is possible either. The `-t` is designed to jump to a tag. Technically, the tag maps an identifier (the tag itself) to an ex command, with that ex command usually being a search which leads to the tag location. You could thus in theory modify the tags file to execute :ts however such thing is probably disallowed. See `:h tag-security`.